# DataType Of Pyspark Column Expression

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark

I wish to get the DataType of a pyspark column expression.

For example,

```
(df_a.a. == df_b.b)
```

Is a column of type Boolean, however since said column isn't part of a Dataframe I cannot call 'dtypes' on it. Is there a way to get the columns datatype without it being part of a dataframe?

Comment: *"... columns datatype without it being part of a dataframe"* -- then what is it part of? why is it a "column"?

Comment: Any operation on a dataframe column returns another "column", even though it is not part of a dataframe.
You can define columns without a dataframe e.g. `col('col_name')`